# Gif player in iPad

Tags: ipad

So I import gifs files from my PC to my iPad but it just frozen like a pic not moving, so what app can I use to play gifs in iPad I've tried some but they can't detect gifs from my iPad, the album shows 0 gifs meanwhile I have abt 200 gifs I've imported.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPad is jailbroken, you can install **GIFViewer** which will let you play GIFs in the iOS Photos app.

Comment: Oh But iTunes or iTools don't show it's jailbroken and I don't have any cyldia something I forgot the name of the application that show it's jailbroken, and when I try to delete apps they're all moving/shaking, would you pls tell me how to know it's already jailbroken?

Comment: @user If you don't know your device is jailbroken, it probably isn't. For the record, I believe the app you are referring to is *Cydia*.

Comment: Yes cydia, I don't have that kind of stuffs, so is there any other than gifviewer? The free one?